# Create columns based on whether specific substrings exist in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, text-classification

I have a DataFrame with some 270,000 books and I'd like to get_dummies based on the `Book-Title`, but only use a select number of words. In the end, I'd like to use 200-300 really distinguishing words, like 'Mystery', 'Murder', 'Classic', and 'Science' and see if they're in the `Book-Title` for each book. I'd like a column for each one of these words that is filled with 0's if the word isn't found and 1's if it is found.

If I try to get_dummies for the *entire* column, I end up with hundreds of thousands of different columns and I don't have the RAM to do that kind of processing.

Below is an example of what I'd like. I already have a list of the 200 most-frequent words among the Book Titles, I just don't know how to make columns from this list.

Input:

```
    ISBN        Book-Title                       Book-Author            Year-Of-Publication     Publisher
0   0195153448  Classical Mythology              Mark P. O. Morford     2002     Oxford University Press
1   0002005018  Clara Callan                     Richard Bruce Wright   2001     HarperFlamingo Canada
2   0060973129  Decision in Normandy             Carlo D Este           1991     HarperPerennial
3   0374157065  Flu: The Story of the Great...   Gina Bari Kolata       1999     Farrar Straus Giroux
4   0393045218  The Mummies of Urumchi           E. J. W. Barber        1999     W. W. Norton &amp; Company
```

Desired output:

```
    ISBN        Title                          'World'  'Mythology'  'Mystery'  'Mummies'
0   0195153448  Classical Mythology             0        1            0          0
1   0002005018  Clara Callan                    0        0            0          0
2   0060973129  Decision in Normandy            0        0            0          0
3   0374157065  Flu: The Story of the Great...  0        0            0          0
4   0393045218  The Mummies of Urumchi          0        0            0          1
```

Thank you in advance!

Adam

Comment: If RAM is the issue you can use google colab as its fast and has a good memory.

Comment: That's what I'm using right now. It's restarted a few times because I'm going above the limit.

Comment: This is one-hot encoding, you could use [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) with the `binary` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to `'Book-Title'` column that iterates over the list of words to check if each word exists in each entry; and convert the output to a DataFrame:

```
lst = ['World', 'Mythology', 'Mystery', 'Mummies']
df[lst] = df['Book-Title'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([int(w in x) for w in lst]))
```

Output:

```
                    Book-Title  World  Mythology  Mystery  Mummies
0          Classical Mythology      0          1        0        0
1                 Clara Callan      0          0        0        0
2         Decision in Normandy      0          0        0        0
3  Flu: The Story of the Great      0          0        0        0
4       The Mummies of Urumchi      0          0        0        1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop and iterate through a list of your keywords, creating a new column for each keyword. Keep in mind that you might want to compare lower case words to lower case words so that the case isn't an issue.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['Classical Mythology','Clara Callan', 'Decision in Normandy', 'Flu: The Story of the Great...', 'The Mummies of Urumchi']})

for keyword in ['World','Mythology','Mystery','Mummies']:
    df[keyword] = df['Title'].apply(lambda x: 1 if keyword.lower() in x.lower() else 0)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
                            Title  World  Mythology  Mystery  Mummies
0             Classical Mythology      0          1        0        0
1                    Clara Callan      0          0        0        0
2            Decision in Normandy      0          0        0        0
3  Flu: The Story of the Great...      0          0        0        0
4          The Mummies of Urumchi      0          0        0        1
```